# Truncate text whilst maintaining button positioning inside parent span

Tags: html, css

Came upon an issue using Vue package: [Vue Select.](https://vue-select.org/)

When using the multiple select option. You are able to select multiple values within the same select. However when values are *"too long"* they escape the select field.
[image: vue-select documentation example]

I figured truncating the content would be a decent solution as this would make sure the inputs stay within their input container.

[image: example of truncating the selected option content]

```
.vs__selected {
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

However, there is another problem with this that I have not been able to figure out. Shown in above screenshot of the "truncating solution" the deselect button is also truncated which is problematic as this is a core functionality that can't and shouldn't be lost. Problem is that this span element containing the text and deselect button does not have a wrapping element for the text.

Chrome dev tools inspect:

```
<span class="vs__selected">
    Lorum Ipsum
    <button type="button" title="Lorum Ipsum" aria-label="Lorum Ipsum" class="vs__deselect">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="10" height="10"></svg>
    </button>
</span>
```

How would I be able to truncate the text and "exclude" the button from this without being able to manipulate/add a wrapping element around the text?

Comment: Probably quite easy to solve, if you positioned the button absolute.

Comment: @CBroe that has definitely been something I tried, and suppose in hindsight I should have added to my question. However, problem with this is that it will maintain it's assumed "position in the string" instead of having a fixed position in the span. I've updated my question to include an example of the absolute deselect button behaviour.

Comment: Have you applied `position: relative` to the span, to make it the reference point for absolute positioning of children? And did you specify any top/left/bottom/right for the button itself?

Comment: Cheers @CBroe, I've given the parent (span) a position: relative like you explained, and then gave it a padding-right to reserve space for the deselect button. Deselect button has position: absolute and right: 0. I am not that knowledgeable in css, so thanks for the explanation. Learned something new